# Specify the format of cells in EXEL by different values for each row

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I have a big exel table (120 x 40), where are

```
D3, D4, D5 - days
mean - mean value of D3:D5
-20% - mean value - 20% of it 
+20% - mean value + 20% to it
```

I have to highlight the values (D3, D4, D5) of each row which are not in a range from  -20% to +20%. I know that I can use cell formatting and add there the range of cells, but in this case it always fixes, but I woul like it change from row to row. For instance:

```
        D3   D4   D5      mean      -20%      +20%
row 1   1    1    0       1.00      0.80      1.20    - highlight 0 (not in range)
row 2   26   27   31      28.00     22.40     33.60   - no highlight (everything in range)
row 3   11   27   31      23.00     28.40     27.60   - highlight 11 and 31 (not in range)
```

Can I use macros or any other methods to avoid doing it manually?

I've tried to use "formatting rules for" but in this case I cannot make different range for different rows

Comment: share a copy / sample of your sheet with an example of the desired output

Comment: here first 7 rows are colored how I want them

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bDaxXZfjeL39A5qIxFRjgFsapjdRiNT_kRdZ-oM6ckE/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=((C31>=($F31-$F31*20%))*(C31<=($F31+$F31*20%)))=0
```

[image]

---

### UPDATE

red:

```
=((B2>=$F2)*(B2<=$G2))=0
```

rest green...

[image]